# Как в editText слева добавить векторное изображение

Tags: android

Как в `editText` слева добавить векторное изображение

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_first_address"
```

типа этого

```
<EditText
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

через xml никак не поставить, еще пока не дали такой возможности.
Но программно можно  (при условии, что вы используете appcompat-v7:23.2.1) =)

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.vector,0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
...     
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_vector" />
```

или

```
    EditText eTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTxt);
    eTxt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.my_vector, 0, 0, 0);
```

Вам необходимо предварительно подготовить вектор, помним что в edit_text согласно Material guidline

> icon = 32x32 dp